# Adding a variable into a page - wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

When I create pages within Wordpress, the call to action links on those pages always have the same URL. I want to be able to globalize this variable but am struggling to find a good way to do it.

If I were making simple PHP pages I could simply include e.g.

```
$URLpath = "http://example.com/my/page";
```

Then call this in the html:

```
<a href="<?=$URLpath?>">Call to action</a>
```

Obviously I can't do this within the Wordpress CMS as it renders as `<?=$URLpath?>`

I could add, say, `<a href="#MyVariable#">Call to action</a>` and replace after the page loads using javascript replace over the whole block of html, but it doesn't feel efficient to do this.

Is there a better way? I'm pretty new to Wordpress.

Comment: why couldn't you include a php script in wordpress?

Comment: Are you trying to add php code through wordpress visual editor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a shortcode in your functions.php file that prints your cta, or better create a plugin with some parameter that manages this link.

For example in functions.php you could add

```
function cta_func( $atts ){
   $URLpath = "http://example.com/my/page";       
   return '<a href="'.$URLpath.'">Call to action</a>';
}
add_shortcode( 'cta', 'cta_func' );
```

inside your pages/post you can write simply this shortcode.

```
...
[cta]
...
```

Further infos about shortcodes are in the reference of codex
https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API

Comment: This doesn't technically answer my question but did give me an alternative way of thinking, so awarded the answer - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A good way to do this within WordPress is to use their [wp_localize_script()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script)

In your **functions.php** file you could use as:

```
// For sake of example I will put your data inside an array,
// but you can set a single value.
$dataForJS = array(
  $URLPath => "http://example.com/my/page"
);

// wp_localize_script() takes 3 parameters:
// 1. Name of the registered script, this is the name you used in wp_register_script()
//    here I am naming it "main" but it can be anything.
// 2. Name of the variable.
//    This name is then available in your JS and will contain your data.
// 3. The data you want to pass, it can be a single value or array
wp_localize_script( 'main', 'd', $dataForJS );
```

In your JavaScript, you will be able to access this data by just calling the variable `d`.

What this does is that if the page requests the "main" script, WordPress will add a `script` tag with your data inside it and makes sure it is placed before your "main" script runs.

Answer (score 0):

[wp_add_inline_script()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_add_inline_script/) was introduced in WordPress Version 4.5, and is now the best practice for adding a JavaScript variable to a page.

```
wp_add_inline_script( 'mainjs', sprintf("const myDomain = '%s'", MY_DOMAIN), 'before' );
```